# calling recursive function fom if statement condition in python3

Tags: if-statement, python-3.4

I know python doesn't allow assignments statements to be used in expressions,
but does it apply for recursive functions.

C code:

```
if (ret = recursive_function("asdf")) return ret;
```

Python3

```
ret = recursive_function("asdf")
if ret:
    return ret
```

Are those 2 codes equivalent? If not how to rewrite it to Python3
Another example. Will it work in Python3?

```
if recursive_function("asdf"):
    #sth
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sufficiently-typed application, yes, these are equivalent.
However, it appears that you're using this in the looser, C-based sense: you test whether the return value happens to evaluate to **True** or **False**.  These do *not* align perfectly between C++ and Python.  There are many similarities (for similar reasons), but you need to check before you depend on the value.

Better yet, make a specific check on the return value.  What is the "false" response you anticipate from the function?  For instance, you might want to use

```
ret = recursive_function("asdf")
if ret is not null:
    return ret
```

Does that get you moving forward?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm writing a recursive descent parser so there's many if statements and function calling. I don't know if it's better way out there how to implement it in Python3. Only this classic old style c way ...

Comment: I see.  The false/null/empty return denotes bad syntax, then?

Comment: Also, is there some reason you're doing recursive descent instead of using a parser generator?  There are tools that accept BNF and spit back a working scanner & parser.  LEX/YACC is an early example.